# Usando BASE64 no Java

Tags: java, packages

**Problema:**

---

Não consigo importar as classes `BASE64Decoder` e `BASE64Encoder`, existem N código que utilizam elas e quando vou usa-los tudo que está relacionado não funciona justamente por que elas não são encontradas.

---

```
import sun.misc.BASE64Decoder;
import sun.misc.BASE64Encoder;
```

Preciso entender por que não encontro o pacote `sun.misc` e a classes `BASE64Decoder` e `BASE64Encoder`. Quem pode ajudar?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Desde o Java 6, você pode usar os métodos estáticos `printBase64Binary` e `parseBase64Binary` da classe [`DatatypeConverter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/DatatypeConverter.html#parseBase64Binary%28java.lang.String%29).

Veja um exemplo:

```java
String base64 = DatatypeConverter.printBase64Binary("Blá = 1".getBytes("UTF-8"));
System.out.println(base64);

String original = new String(DatatypeConverter.parseBase64Binary(base64), "UTF-8");
System.out.println(original);
```

Isso irá imprimir:

> QmzDoSA9IDE=
>
> Blá = 1

Comment: Essa codificação é URL-safe?

Comment: @Piovezan O javadoc e o [código](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7-b147/javax/xml/bind/DatatypeConverterImpl.java#DatatypeConverterImpl._printBase64Binary%28byte%5B%5D%2Cint%2Cint%2Cchar%5B%5D%2Cint%29) não fazem menção disso, mas fiz uma breve pesquisa e verifiquei que o padrão [Base64](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64#Examples) pode conter os caracteres `=`, `+` e `/`, portanto não seria adequado usá-lo em URLs. Algumas pessoas sugerem fazer uma substituição de caracteres para tornar o resultado *url-safe*.

Comment: Resposta, me ajudou de novo. hahahaha. Base64 nativa e assim não precisamos usar API's como (org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64), para usar um único método. hahaha. .